# Seem having vs Seem to have

Tags: verbs

I'm back to you with a new doubt.

I wonder if the phrase n.1 is totally wrong or if it's possible to use it in some cases.

1) This road "seems having" no end.
2) This road "seems to have" no end.

I've found somewhere on the web some people using the first form. Like "They seem having fun".

Thanks in advance. Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is totally wrong. You cannot follow the verb "to seem" with a gerund or present participle.

"They seem having fun" is also incorrect. It has the appearance of being written by a non-native. The correct phrase is, "They seem to be having fun."

Here is a comprehensive discussion on the usage of seem

> Seem
>
> from English Grammar Today
>
> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/seem

Comment: @ Chasly from UK. Can't tell if they are non-native. But I've seen more than one on the web. Probably is something like a "slang" or just people that don't care so much about grammar. ;-) Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Marco - it's always helpful if you can give actual examples in your question. That gives us context. Do you have links to any such examples? You could add them to your question.

Comment: _Seem_ doesn't take a gerund complement; only infinitives and _that_-clauses. _Seem_ and _appear_ have virtually identical syntactic restrictions, so substituting _appear_ for _seem_ is an interesting test. How does **They appear having fun* sound? It's totally ungrammatical for me.